# How to perform bulk delete by query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible?
I'm trying to do this via ts:

```
                query: {
                    bool: {
                        must: [
                            {
                                term: {
                                    chat: chatId
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                term: {
                                    custDomain: domain
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

And getting: `'[illegal_argument_exception] Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected a simple value for field [query] but found [START_OBJECT]', path: '/_bulk'`

If it's not possible to perform bulk delete by query, should I add some index like "custDomain_chatId"?
I'm trying to delete multiply **chatId** with same **custDomain**. There are a lot of chatId to be deleted.'[illegal_argument_exception] Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected a simple value for field [query] but found [START_OBJECT]',
path: '/_bulk'

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete by query API as mentioned in the documentation [Delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) it works the same way as search API so the matched documents will be deleted which perform the desired action **Bulk delete**.

- NodeJS example of using delete by query API and Elasticsearch SDK:

  ```
    client.deleteByQuery({
    index: "target_index_name_to_query",
    refresh: true,
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [{
            terms: {
              chatId: [value1, value2]
            }
          },
          {
            terms: {
              custDomain: domain
            }
          }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
  ```

For more examples on how to build term query refer to the documentation [Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Comment: Is it possible to perform multiply conditions delete(bulk)? Like (chatId == 1 or chatId ==2 ...) and custDomain == CONSTANT in one query

Comment: yes it's doable because term accepts single value or array of values so it should be like this 
term: {
            chatId: [ value1 , value2]
          }
I will edit the original answer code sample with your desired query
you can refer to the documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Getting error: Error: [parsing_exception] [term] query does not support array of values

Comment: yeah you have to use terms instead of term.
i have fixed it in the answer you can use it

Answer (score 0):

**ES 8.11, 2024-01**

I don't know what the situation was in 2020, but maybe you could consider doing a [bulk delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-api-request-body). What Mohamed Assem is describing is not a bulk delete, but a `_delete_by_query`. Study that page to learn how bulk operations are performed.

The downside of this is that it might be quite complicated to determine the `_id`s of all the LuceneDocuments (index documents) you need to delete. Typically you might have to run a _search query to find these `_id`s on the basis of your query. You must have these `_id`s to do a bulk delete.

Then you have the faff of making a bulk string conforming to the strict string format required. It's fairly feasible when you get the hang of it. And these bulk operations are pretty fast.